# SSH publickey error when trying to push to server using git

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, amazon-web-services, git

I am trying to use this tutorial to set up a git remote repo on my server:
http://toroid.org/ams/git-website-howto

But when I try to push to the server, I get this error:

```
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

So it seems like git can't ssh the server because of some auth key issue. I can SSH into the server fine from Terminal by using `ssh aws1` due to the set up of my ssh config file.

~/.ssh/config file:

```
Host aws1
        HostName 54.235.193.228
        User ubuntu
        IdentityFile ~/.ssh/ec2_key.pem
```

The git commands I am using to add the remote and push:

```
git remote add web  ssh://54.235.193.228/home/ubuntu/somedirectory.git 

git push web +master:refs/heads/master
```

I think my problem is i don't quite understand fully how to use ssh key-pairs. The tutorial says:

> "I assume that the web site will live on a server to which you have ssh
>   access, and that things are set up so that you can ssh to it without
>   having to type a password (i.e., that your public key is in
>   ~/.ssh/authorized_keys and you are running ssh-agent locally)."

I don't know what ssh-agent is and I don't even have an authorized_keys file on my machine (I do have one called known_hosts). I thought using the ssh config file would be adequate because that allows me to ssh from the terminal without a password but apparently that is not correct. What am I doing wrong?

Server: EC2 instance, Ubuntu 12.04, AWS elastic ip

Dev Machine: OS X 10.7.5, zsh shell

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you simply use `aws1` in your remote ? This way, you can reuse your .ssh/config configuration for `aws1`:

```
git remote add web ssh://aws1/home/ubuntu/somedirectory.git
```

Git uses the `ssh` command to connect, so everything that applies to the `ssh` command applies to Git.

Otherwise, you will need to specify the URL, user in the remote, as in `ssh://ubuntu@54.235.93.228/...`. And because there is no way to specify which private key should be used, you need to configure it in `.ssh/config` anyway.